# Windows 10 Desktop and Taskbar Shortcuts Have Stopped Working

Tags: windows, windows-10, shortcuts

My **Windows 10 Enterprise N** desktop has recently updated and now **shortcuts** do not work either from the desktop, the taskbar or the Start menu.

Right clicking, going to 'file location' and then clicking on the .exe file gets the program running - but shortcuts have just stopped working?!?
A couple of exceptions are Microsoft Edge from the taskbar and file folders from the desktop. Also a Word .docx file on the desktop opens fine.

This has got me beat. I have restored security settings, run registry checking programs and looked through countless 'help' sites - including Microsoft's.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Start by running a `chkdsk` followed by a `Sfc /scannow` and see if they report any errors.

Comment: Thanks. I did run those again but no errors reported and no change to the problem.